# Problems while writing to a file using a python script that is ran from a php script

Tags: javascript, python, php

So I'm building a website where I can use buttons to activate various scripts. I want to be able to press a button on the website and have the script run on a raspberry pi (where the website is hosted). This has all worked fine up until I tried to have the PHP file activate a python script that could read/write to .json files. I don't think that there are any errors in either of the scripts because if I run the PHP script from the terminal whilst connected to the pi all the commands execute perfectly. However, when I call the PHP script in a browser nothing happens.

This is the contents of the PHP file:

```
<?php 
     system ( "gpio -g mode 24 out" );
     system ( "gpio -g  write 24 0" );
     system ( "gpio -g mode 18 out" );
     system ( "gpio -g  write 18 1" );
     system ( "sudo python3 RLY1on.py" );
 ?>
```

The contents of the python file are as follows:

```
import json

a = open("RelayState.json", "r")
data = json.load(a)
a.close()

data["RLY1"] = 1

a = open("RelayState.json", "w")
json.dump(data, a)
a.close()
```

As I said previously there weren't any errors whilst running this in the console so I'm not sure why it wouldn't run when called in a browser.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: It's not "called in a browser", it's "called from PHP". The browser can't run commands on your server.

Comment: Are you sure that file path is correct? Specifying the full path to the Python script may help.

Comment: Can't you run a python script instead of running PHP to then run python?

Comment: All of the paths are correct and i cant run python instead of PHP

Comment: That sudo is the problem, the script is executed by the php owner, who is not sudo (and must not be) One unsafe solution is to modify the sudoers file. But try to avoid the sudo altogether

Answer (score 1):

So on the off chance that anyone else gets this issue ill post what worked for me.

As I stated above there was no error in the paths or the code with the exception of the sudo used in the PHP program.

The PHP program wasn't run in sudo therefore running the python as sudo caused an error. This means that I had to change the permissions of the file I was trying to edit, I did this by using the following command:

`chmod a+rw RelayState.json`

This means that any user can edit the file with no permissions.